# Expo EAS build fails on Android: run gradlew

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

Expo EAS build fails on Android: run gradlew

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error it was enough just to change gradle-7.3.3-all.zip by gradle-7.4-all.zip in yourappName\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

ps : run npx expo prebuild --no-install --platform android before to have android folder

Comment: what can be the solution now that isn't working again

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Expo EAS build use Gradle version `7.3.3` and some modules require Gradle version `7.4` at minimum.

EAS Build doesn't provide a direct way to change the Gradle version but it provides presets for building infrastructure images.

In the `eas.json` file, try to use latest image, which contains latest versions of build tools.

```js
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.38.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle",
        "image": "latest"
      }
    }
  },
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: an error in "Run gredlew" in Android build (no problem with iOS build) when I upgraded to Expo SDK 47.

The good thing was that I already had a successful build with Expo SDK 47, so I began to downgrade one by one the third-party packages I am using to the same versions of that successful build.

In the end, the culprit was @stripe/stripe-react-native. The build was successful again reverting back to version 0.13.1 from 0.19.0.

In your case, it might be any other third-party package, so I suggest going through the same process.

EDIT 26/01/2023: Instead of downgrading @stripe/stripe-react-native, I followed Kudo's advice [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20597#issuecomment-1367943522):

> the @stripe/stripe-react-native@0.19.0 requires android compileSdkVersion 33. you could use expo-build-properties to change the compileSdkVersion to 33 in a managed project: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/#pluginconfigtypeandroid